# Interesting/Innovative Open Source tools for indie games

Tags: tools, open-source

Just out of curiosity, I want to know opensource tools or projects that can add some interesting features to indie games, preferably those that could only be found on big-budget games.

**EDIT:** As suggested by The Communist Duck and Joe Wreschnig, I'm putting the examples as answers.

**EDIT 2:** Please do not post tools like PyGame, Inkscape, Gimp, Audacity, Slick2D, Phys2D, Blender (except for interesting plugins) and the like. I know they are great tools/libraries and some would argue *essential* to develop good games, but I'm looking for more rare projects. Could be something really specific or niche, like generating realistic trees and plants, or realistic AI for animals.

Comment: I know what FOSS is but what is Floss? Google keeps taking me to dental floss.

Comment: Hehe, it's the same: FLOSS stands for Free-Libre-Open-Source Software..

Comment: Could we have a title change to just open source tools or something similar? I'm just wondering it could generate more interest with a more understandable title.

Comment: Also, maybe separate OpenSteer and the motion capture one into answers?

Comment: I edited the title to include Open Source instead of FLOSS.

Comment: @AttackingHobo: Thanks for the edit. I thought FLOSS was more widespread (guess too much time spent on freegamedev.net :D)

Comment: @Commie Duck: I guess I could put them into answers, but I don't see the benefit. They're there to be a guide, so to avoid common tools like Blender/PyGame/Bullet etc

Comment: The benefit of putting them in as answers is that we can edit and vote on them as answers. That's the point of CW.

Comment: When he said it, I believe he meant individual answers.

Comment: @Noctrine: Yes, but that would imply that the best answer is that which names "the best" project, when I believe the best answer would be the one that lists more -relevant- projects than others

Comment: Seems that it would more imply the project that is most interesting. But I get your reasoning.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question is quickly degenerating into "list all the open source game libraries you know of". Even for CW lists, I'd prefer more focused questions; and CW lists should really have one answer per answer.

Comment: @Joe W.: As you wish, though I thought my 2nd edit & comments narrowed the scope of possible answers. I was aiming for CW list because someone may know a certain project that could add value to a game, that I couldn't have thought of otherwise. Say, I might have asked for the best AI Frameworks out there, effectively leaving out interesting things like the ones -later- added by slf.

Comment: @Gastón: Google does a better job collecting tangentially-related links than we ever will. This site is good at concrete questions and answers.

Comment: @Joe W.: I did my bit of research before putting my question over here. However, I wanted to hear other people's thought on the subject, rather than wander aimlessly through the Internet. Still, thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: @Everyone: In a vain attempt to at least keep a base level of useful curation in this list, please list only open source projects.

Comment: (And I am also voting to close again because of the vagary of the question and because the number of multiple and duplicate answers here is ridiculous.)

Comment: @JW: Would you mind sharing a place where I could post this question? (I'm not being ironic)

Comment: @Gastón: gamedev.net, gamasutra user blogs, indiegamer formers, freegamedev.net, tigsource forums, etc. There's no shortage of places on the Internet to have open discussions of game development.

Answer (score 26):

I think [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) and [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx) are extremely obvious, but beyond that...

API

- [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) 3D Physics engine, used in AAA titles
- [Chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) Flexible and Powerful 2D Physics engine in straight C
- [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) Another robust and popular 2D physics engine
- [FPMath](http://code.google.com/p/fpmath/) C++ template based math library, specifically for dealing with Fixed Point arithmetic (requires [Boost](http://www.boost.org/))
- [OpenSteer](http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/) Steering Behaviors for Autonomous Characters
- [Xiph](http://www.xiph.org/) home of lots of open source audio and video alternatives like Vorbis and Theora

Tools

- [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) 3D Modeling Tool with a great deal of functionality and support for many different file formats
- [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) 2D Raster image manipulation, very robust feature set
- [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) 2D Vector image manipulation, based on SVG
- [sfxr](http://www.drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html) Sound effect generator, great if you're in a hurry or don't have an audio specialist
- [FFMpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) record, convert and stream audio and video

Engines

- [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/) cross platform, open source, networking engine for game programmers (RakNet 4 is free for independent Developers that gross $50K or less)
- [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) open source high performance realtime 3D engine written and usable in C++ and also available for .NET languages.
- [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) One of the most popular open source game engines, and for good reason

Mobile Specific (since that's what I'm into at the moment)

- [Oolong](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/) game engine that includes much of the above mentioned, optimized for PowerVR on the iphone, maintained by [Wolfgang Engel](http://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,158706/) and [Erwin Coumans](http://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,182064/) of Grand Theft Auto fame
- [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) free Objective-C based iPhone specific port of the Python original, very easy to use and lots of community support
- [VFPMath](http://code.google.com/p/vfpmathlibrary/) Crazy fast math library written mostly with inline assembly to take advantage of the ARM processor
- [AndEngine](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/) 2D OpenGL Game Engine for Android

More Exotic:

- [Canonical Multitouch](https://launchpad.net/canonical-multitouch) Gesturing system for all multitouch input devices and more
- [1 dollar](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/) and [N dollar](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/ndollar.html) stroke recognition systems.  Links are for javascript implementations, but they have been ported to many other languages
- [OpenFoam](http://www.openfoam.com/) Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) library in C++, see also [FireFOAM](http://code.google.com/p/firefoam-dev/) an extension for modeling fire
- [Moody](http://moody.politespider.com/index.php) an n-Model body development framework I found interesting, primary usage would be Celestial Mechanics and Astrodynamics.  Includes a viewer tool for files.
- [ofxMSAFluid](http://memo.tv/ofxmsafluid) Fluid dynamics simulation framework
- [Gromacs](http://www.gromacs.org/) - "versatile package to perform molecular dynamics, i.e. simulate the Newtonian equations of motion for systems with hundreds to millions of particles"

Comment: Thanks slf, impressive list indeed, though I was aiming at more "exotic" libraries, targeting say AI or human motion. Physics libraries are good too, as long as they handle fluid and particles (and not just good ol' rigid bodies mechanics)

Comment: added exotics :)

Comment: Now, that's what I'm talking about ;D

Answer (score 16):

[Recast & Detour](http://code.google.com/p/recastnavigation/) is an awesome open source navigation mesh / path finding library. It's potentially got more appeal to larger titles than indie games, but I could definitely see it being useful to anyone wanting decent multi-agent movement in any 3D game.

The [developer's (Mikko Mononen) blog](http://digestingduck.blogspot.com/) also has several interesting entries around steering, path finding and navigation in general.

And it's actively maintained / developed.

Comment: Wow, nice library. I'll take a closer look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I pulled some audio gems from my memory with help from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_audio_software).

- [Ardour (OS X, Linux)](http://ardour.org/) - DAW
- [RoseGarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/) - DAW
- [Linux MuliMedia Studio](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) - FLOSS FL Studio clone
- [PureData](http://puredata.info/) - FLOSS alternative to Max/MSP. Good for prototyping audio effects and - - dynamic music systems. Spore devs used this for generative music
- [OpenMPT (ModPlug)](http://openmpt.org/) - Tracker, useful for music on phones
- [Spear](http://www.klingbeil.com/spear/) - Spectrum analyzer and more

Answer (score 5):

Examples of tools/projects I found interesting are:

- [CMU's Motion Capture Database](http://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion)
- [OpenSteer](http://www.google.com.uy/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopensteer.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=z7flTO2lLMO88gaM3vjVDQ&usg=AFQjCNHxQjLl3mtBNnYDTdW50UHGFUh7Ug&sig2=jrzoX3TmUWQpg9c5tjiaww)
- Biped motion simulation (which I can't seem to find the link)

Answer (score 5):

The following are blender tools:

ANT landscape generator: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/ANT_Landscape

Procedural generation of landscapes which simplifies the generation of complex terrain.

Blended Cities:
http://jerome.le.chat.free.fr/index.php/en/city-engine/news/

Procedural city generation for the artist to quickly generate large cities. For my undergraduate dissertation I added city zoning to this:
http://www.blendernation.com/2010/04/26/city-zoning-modification-for-blended-cities-script/

L-system tree generator:
http://lsystem.liquidweb.co.nz/Examples/tabid/122/Default.aspx

Standalone vegetation generator: http://arbaro.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Wow, those are really nice ones...

Answer (score 5):

- [Ivy](http://graphics.uni-konstanz.de/~luft/ivy_generator/) Complex vegetation generator

Comment: oops, sorry, the other ones weren't open source. Good editing.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit of an old topic but has some other recent posts, so I'm going to throw in my own voxel library. It's great for creating environment with smooth voxel terrain or 'cubic' environments like Minecraft. Environments can then be modified in real time and it should be easy to integrate with most 3D engines. It's under the zlib license for free for commercial use.

Have a look at http://www.thermite3d.org for more information.

Comment: Funny that you mention Thermite3D, just a couple of days ago I stumbled upon its site. Nice tool you've made!

Comment: You should note that PolyVox has moved websites and is now at http://www.volumesoffun.com/polyvox-about/

Answer (score 5):

The [Verse Protocol and reference Engine](http://www.quelsolaar.com/) is astonishingly awesome; [check out some discussion of a game made with the engine, and then ... the tools demos](http://vimeo.com/18423305)!  The tools demos will blow you away....

Comment: Actually, too awesome to be true...I may have to check it out :)

Answer (score 5):

- [Enet](http://enet.bespin.org/) For your networking needs
- [ODE](http://opende.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) For physical needs
- [Cartwheel3d](http://code.google.com/p/cartwheel-3d/) Physics animation...
- [Animation system](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=45260) Ogre3d based animation blending framework

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of tools I found just today:

- [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/)
- [BulletML](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~cs8k-cyu/bulletml/) - markup language for describing bullet barrages, commonly seen in shoot-em-up games

Answer (score 2):

These two probably go without saying, but:

- OpenGL (rendering)
- OpenAL (audio)

are both high-quality industry staples that are open source and cross-platform. Always worth considering.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but those two are (besides totally awesome) quite...mundane, let say. I was gearing towards more "exotic" libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in an innovative 3D framework, checkout [Google's O3D](http://code.google.com/p/o3d/wiki/GettingStarted) that allows development of 3D games for WebGL compatible browsers, such as Chrome 9 (beta), Firefox's nighly build; Minefield & Safari WebKit (iPhone)

Checkout [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIckuRRR-DE) of the body browser made with this new technology if you don't yet have one of these browsers :)

Answer (score 2):

I came across some tools for 2D game development recently that I find quite exciting:

- [SWFSheet](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2948) converts a SWF created in Flash (including animations created using Actionscript) into a spritesheet or series of sprites
- [Zwoptex](http://zwoptexapp.com/) packs a series of sprites into a spritesheet and emits metadata about their position
- [Texture Packer](http://texturepacker.com/) is an alternative program which does the same

Personally, I think the Flash authoring tools are amazing and dearly miss them when I work in XNA or Java. Which is why I'm excited about giving the above a spin.

Answer (score 0):

AnimKit is a small basic open source skeletal animation system with skinning, that loads the data straight from a Blender .blend file. It uses the liberal ZLib license, like Bullet.

The code is portable, it works under Windows, Linux, OSX and some iOS and Android samples are planned.

See http://code.google.com/p/gamekit/downloads/detail?name=animkit_src_r1020.zip
and http://gamekit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=144

Answer (score 0):

#### [Wiki: PxTone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PxTone), [Orig: PxTone](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA022293/pxtone/index.html) - [[Tutorial](http://buzinkai.net/PXTone/tutorial/)] - [[Download](http://buzinkai.net/PXTone/pxtone_0903.zip)]

A japanese music/beat/tone maker!

[image: PxTone]